# Selecting a default radion button in d3 from button event

Tags: d3.js, radio-button

I'm using d3. I have a radio button group called #risk. This includes values "apple", "Orange", "Lemon".
I have a separate button on the screen which resets the value back to "Apple". So if they select "Lemon" then click reset, the new value will be "Apple". Any idea how I would do this. Having some difficulty achieving something that should be pretty trivial.
Here id the radio button code:

```
<div id="risk">
<form>
    <span>
    <input type="radio" class="risk" name="mode" value= Apple">
    <label> All</label>
    </span>
    <span>
    <input type="radio" class="risk" name="mode" value= Orange">
    <label> All</label>
    </span>
    <span>
    <input type="radio" class="risk" name="mode" value= Lemon">
    <label> All</label>
    </span>
</form>
```

And here is the code for the update button:

```
d3.select("#resetChart")
.on("click",function() {
d3.selectAll("#risk").selectAll("input") //somehow make this select a radio button
});
```

My last edit was rejected. I'm not sure on what basis. If this doesn't fit the criteria could you please let me know what I need to do to improve it? Many thanks :)

Comment: You'll have to show us some code. How are those values used?